# Timer to do a Database Auto clean every 24h

Tags: c#, oracle

I have an oracle database and need to check certain tables every 24h and do a delete. I have to write a service in c# for this. Should i use Timers or is there a better solution for this task?

Comment: Is there any real need for you to put the timer in the code itself, rather than just scheduling a task within Windows (via the Windows Task Scheduler)?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle has a scheduler of it's own, not surprisingly called [`Oracle Scheduler`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedover001.htm#ADMIN12354). You can schedule an arbitrary piece of PL/SQL code or call a stored procedure that does the deletions. There is no need to bring any external program or scheduling mechanism.

Comment: Well i don't have much experience with Oracle Sheduler that's why i want to do it with a c# code.Every 24h i call the select and than delete command. I am just not sure if Timers are the right thing for this

Comment: @Georg if you are not sure about timers, you probably don't have much experience with C# and services either. Maybe this is a good opportunity to learn about the Oracle Scheduler? From my experience, it's never a good idea to reinvent the wheel and try to do something better than a multi-million dollar corporation already did. Especially not if "doing it better" starts with asking online if doing it this way is a good idea.